# Margin changes with Jquery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If you drag and drop a few elements, you will notice the margin between some of the elements becomes thinner. How can I fix this?

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/fKQsG/

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See, the `LI` has a property of `display: inline;`, which will count the spaces too. Replace it with `float: left;` and it would work.

```
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 50px; float: left; list-style-type:none; background:black; }
```

I changed `width: 50px; float: left;`.

**Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fKQsG/1/**

Comment: This is a common issue we come across! :) Glad it helped you! :)